# What is the point of object/instance private access?

Tags: scala

In Scala you can create objects with private variables that can only be accessed by the declaring instance of the object.

```
class Counter {
    private[this] var value = 0

    def isLess( other : Counter) = value < other.value // syntax error
}
```

Why is this useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It would be useful if you need to absolutely make sure no other object gained access to a variable, even members of the same class.

The main case I know of here is when you are making a companion object to a class and don't want to prevent access between the companion object and the instances of the class.

It can also be a small performance advantage due to enabling direct field access instead of going through an accessor method.